# Java spring Rest and Android

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have rest service with java back-end. i use Spring Security. What steps do I need to do in order to make authorization available to Android apps?
At the moment all works in the web version. This is Spring Security config.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        // отключена защита csrf на время тестов
        http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService);
    }
```

P.S. Or any steps to do and no matter who acts as the client.
(i can authonticate via postman) I'm interested in the approach, whether it is necessary separately to implement in order to log in via the Android app was possible?